# ¿Para que sirve el IAggregateRoot interface?

Tags: .net, diseño, arquitectura, ddd

estoy aprendiendo algo de DDD lo estoy implementando en .net core. tengo una pregunta que no la he podido resolver en ningún foro, comencemos:

1. suponiendo que tengo la siguiente  clase:
   esta clase representa un usuario hereda de la clase abstracta entidad e implementa IAggregateroot

   ```
    public class User : Entity, IAggregateRoot
   {...}
   ```
2. esta es la clase abs Entidad:
   es algo básica y se que es mejor tener un value object para el id, lo importante es que me represente la entidad como tal

   ```
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        protected string Id;

        protected Entity(Guid? id = null)
        {
            this.Id = id != null ? id.ToString() : new Guid().ToString(); 
        }
    }
   ```
3. lo siquiente y lo que no entiendo es el IAggregateroot
   que rayos hace una interface sin contratos ejejej, he leído que se utiliza como marcador, aun así no entiendo este concepto

   ```
   public interface IAggregateRoot
   {
    //vacío 
   }
   ```

es que no lo utilizo ni en el IRepository:
he visto en diferentes repositorios de githup que utilizan el Entity en vez de IAggregateroot

````
```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    public Task<T> AddAsync(T obj);
}
```
````

entonces, pido de su ayuda para poder determinar para que me sirve la interface IAggregateroot, en donde la puedo utilizar, en que capa se hace el llamado.

teóricamente  el agregado es el que permite hacer de un conjunto de entidades una sola unidad, un solo punto de entrada, sin embargo, en la practica no se como y para que sirve la interface IAggregadoroot. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

IAggregateRoot suele ser una interfaz de marcado (sin contenido) utilizada simplemente para indicar cual es la entidad "pública" del Agregado (AggregateRoot). Es decir, la única entidad a la que se debe hacer referencia desde fuera del propio agregado.
Un ejemplo claro son los Repositorios. Estos solo manejan AggregateRoot ya que son a las únicas entidades a las que deben hacer referencia. Cualquier entidad interna del Agregado no puede ser referenciada directamente por otras entidad o valueobject.